# django annotate queryset with field comparison result

Tags: django, django-queryset, query-expressions

I have a queryset like this:

```
predicts = Prediction.objects.select_related('match').filter(match_id=pk)
```

I need to annotate this with a new field `is_correct`. I need to compare two string fields and the result should be annotated in this new field. the fields that I want to compare are:

- `predict` from Prediction table
- `result` from Match table (that has been joined through `select_related`)

I need to know what expression should I put inside my annotate function; below I have my current code which throughs a `TypeError` exception:

```
predicts = predicts.annotate(is_correct=(F('predict') == F('result')))
```

all help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I found an alternative solution that does the job for me (filtering the Prediction based on Match result using `filter` and `exclude`), but I still like to know how to address this specific case where the new annotated field is the result of the comparison between two other fields of the queryset. For those who may need it, in `Django 2.2` and later the [Nullif database function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#nullif) does a comparison between two fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra) function, a hook for injecting specific clauses into the SQL.

First of all, we must know the names of the apps and the models, or the name of the tables in the database.

Assuming that in your case, the two tables are called "app_prediction" and "app_match".

The sentence would be as follows:

```
Prediction.objects.select_related('match').extra(
    select={'is_correct': "app_prediction.predict = app_match.result"}
)
```

This will add a field called `is_correct` in your result,
in the database, the fields and tables must be called in the same way.

It would be best to see the models.

Comment: this raises an error:  [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='. (102)

Comment: Try a single "=" sign, can you also show the models you have created?